# saving text entered in a text box placed inside a dynamic table

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

i'm new to iOS programming, i want to save the text entered inside a text box placed inside a dynamic table cell where the table cell contents are like accordion.

in view controller table view with 3 dynamic prototype cells are used each cell is named as header,regular and selected respectively and in view controller i used the following code

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell * cell = nil;

switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
    {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Header"];
    }
        break;
    default:
    {
        NSArray * innerData = [self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row - 1];
        if(indexPath.row == self.selectedIndex)
        {
            SelectedCell * tmpCell = (SelectedCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Selected"];
            [tmpCell.label1 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [innerData objectAtIndex:0]]];

            cell = tmpCell;
             tmpCell.textLabel.numberOfLines=2;

        }
        else
        {
            RegularCell * tmpCell = (RegularCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Regular"];
            [tmpCell.label1 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [innerData objectAtIndex:0]]];

            cell = tmpCell;
             tmpCell.textLabel.numberOfLines=2;
        }
    }
        break;
}



return cell;
```

}

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if(indexPath.row == 0)
    return;

if(indexPath.row != self.selectedIndex && self.selectedIndex > 0)
{
    // Selected different row while there is another selected row

    int oldIndex = self.selectedIndex;
    self.selectedIndex = indexPath.row;

    NSArray * innerData = [self.data objectAtIndex:oldIndex - 1];

    [self.data removeObjectAtIndex:oldIndex - 1];

    NSIndexPath * deselectedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:oldIndex inSection:0];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:deselectedIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC),
                   dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                   ^{
                       [self.data insertObject:innerData atIndex:deselectedIndexPath.row - 1];
                       [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:deselectedIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
                       [tableView reloadData];

                       NSArray * innerData = [self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row - 1];
                       [self.data removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row - 1];
                       [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
                       dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.2 * NSEC_PER_SEC),
                                      dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                                      ^{
                                          [self.data insertObject:innerData atIndex:indexPath.row - 1];
                                          [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
                                          [tableView reloadData];
                                      });
                   });
}
else
{
    if(indexPath.row == self.selectedIndex) // selected active row -> close
        self.selectedIndex = -1;
    else                                    // selected inactive row -> open
        self.selectedIndex = indexPath.row;

    NSArray * innerData = [self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row - 1];
    [self.data removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row - 1];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.2 * NSEC_PER_SEC),
                   dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                   ^{
                       [self.data insertObject:innerData atIndex:indexPath.row - 1];
                       [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
                       [tableView reloadData];
                   });
}
```

}

now i want to store the text entered in each field specific to that cell i searched a lot of tutorials but i could not find it

please provide me with suitable solution ASAP

thanks in advance

Comment: can you tell me about the complete functionality of this.. so that i can share an exact code

Comment: i have a table view with dynamic cells when i select each cell a sub view will come as an accordion in that view i have to place a text field or text view where it should act as a comment box for that row every row should have different comments i have to store that value either to user defaults or to sqlite database

Comment: so u will have a textfield or textview out side of tableview. once you select any row then u will show textfield and once user enters info/comment in it it should display in that cell... is this correct?

Comment: no, i am having number of items in my table when i click on one cell it should expand with a comment box where i should enter comments against that item and i have to save it

Comment: I think you are saying the same as @Charan_Giri. 1. Click on Cell. 2. Show UITextField to enter comments 3.Save the comments.

Comment: i want to display both a item which is a label and also a text field in a cell with unique data